# Is の上 required in エスカレーターの上を歩く

Tags: reading-comprehension

> エスカレーターの**上**を歩くと、ほかの人にぶつかって落ちる危険があるため、やめてほしい。
>   Because there's a risk of bumping in to other people and falling when you walk *along the top* of the escalator, we want people to stop doing it.

I'm a bit confused about the use of 上 in this sentence. Can't I just say エスカレーターを歩く? After all, there's no other part of an escalator you can walk on.

I see the same in thing in:
氷の上を歩く

Comment: I can't answer about the escalator--if only because I'm tempted to think it must mean something other than what it appears to be saying (I walk up escalators all the time and it doesn't seem dangerous to me).  But regarding "walking on ice", the use of 上 in 氷の上を歩く makes reasonable sense to me--it is where you're walking.  Nor do we say "we walk ice", and to say 氷を歩く would sound like "walking **through** ice" as 空を飛ぶ means to "fly **through** the sky".

Comment: @A.Ellett Apparently you're not a member of the health and safety police. The article says you must stop and hold the handrail. I'm happy that using 上 makes sense, I'd just like to know if it's necessary.

Comment: You caught me out!  lol.  Guilty as charged.  I suspect that 上 makes sense here in the sense that you can't ride **through** an escalator.  But, I'm not giving an answer exactly because I'm uncertain.

Comment: エスカレーターを歩く is ok.  I don't know British, but I think "when you walk "on" the escalator" is correct. And at this point, I don't feel grammatical weird, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a bit confused about the use of 上 in this sentence.
>   Can't I just say エスカレーターを歩く? After all, there's no other part of an escalator you can walk on.

I agree with you. In this case, it's not necessary, but nonetheless as a Japanese expression, it's not very unusual.

> I see the same in thing in: 氷の上を歩く

氷を歩く becomes unclear and poetic. We don't normally say 土を歩く, but we say 土の上を歩く, 草の上を歩く, though 砂浜を歩く, 歩道を歩く.

I see that we differentiate 'where' and 'on what'; 氷, 土 and 草 are quality or material.